# How to use LIKE in WHERE clause to get first 5 characters of variable?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a variable varchar that always takes in 10 digits. How can I use the LIKE operator to find/use only the first 5 digits of the variable?

my query:

```
variable IN VARCHAR2

SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE SUBSTRING(variable, 1, 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
... WHERE name LIKE '12345%'
```

will match any string that starts 12345. the '%' is a wildcard. You can also use the wildcard to match anywhere in the string: `... WHERE name LIKE '%12345%'` will match a string with 12345 anywhere within it.

Edit for completeness: `WHERE name LIKE '%12345'` will match any string that ends with those five characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE (SUBSTRING(variable, 1, 5) + '%')
```

Comment: I was just thinking my answer needed direct application, and you took care of that.

Comment: Thank you! What is the purpose of the SELECT in front of the SUBSTRING?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use [LEFT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) like this:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE LEFT(name,5)=LEFT(variable,5);
```

Or if you you want to use `LIKE` with a wildcard, you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(variable,5),'%')
```

A few more example in the [Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=233911053c9db27d699bcf09790eba3a)

**Edit:** The above solution is for MySQL/MariaDB because earlier the tag of this question have MySQL but it's also my fault for not recognizing OP description of the datatype `VARCHAR2`. I might as well just post a suggestion related to the rdbms.

So, my first suggestion there using `LEFT()` however Oracle don't have that function, therefore:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE SUBSTR(name,1,5)=SUBSTR(variable,1,5);
```

or using [concatenation operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm)

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE SUBSTR(variable,1,5)||'%'
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3b46252c8f97efa01abafe51aac47630)